# Access every frame's function CPU usage via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity editor profiler, I can visually see every frame's CPU usage, how much does each function take, is there a way to access that information via script?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access those Unity built-in Profiler information in the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't offer so detailed profiler, but next best thing is using .NET stopwatch which allows you to precisely measure time it takes for something to finish.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new 
 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
 stopwatch.Start();
 doSomething();
 stopwatch.Stop();
 Debug.Log ("Time taken for doSomething() to run"+(stopwatch.Elapsed));
 stopwatch.Reset();
```

When designing a method which is important to be very fast I usually create EditorUI with button in it to run the method 100 times and measure times and then average the results.